# How to display category name on article model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to render category field on an article in terms of its name(choice). Currently, it is rendered as an Id. Also, I want to be able to update the article model by entering category name(choice) instead of its Id(I am currently doing this). How can I go about implementing this?

This is what I have so far.

Models

```
class Category(models.Model):

      """ 
      Model for Category
      """ 

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (

        ('Sports', 'Sports'),
        ('Music', 'Music'), 
        ('Drama', 'Drama'),
        ('Money', 'Money'), 
        ('Movies', 'Movies'), 
        ('Cars', 'Cars'),
        ('General', 'General'), 
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='General',null=False, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):

        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
      """
      Model for an Article
      """ 

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)

    body = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False,)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializers

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      """
      Serializer for Article.
      """

    class Meta:
        model = Article

        fields = ('title','description','body',''category')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      """
      Serializer for Category.
      """

    class Meta:
        model = Category

        fields = ('name',)
```

Current output
[image]

Expected output
[image]

Comment: On a note: why use a separate model for category it only has a name that is one of 7 choices? You might as well have the category name as `CharField` on `Article` and avoid the database JOINs.

Comment: @dirkgroten +1 A `CharField` with `choices` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Comment: @dirkgroten, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `ArticleSerializer` to have the `category` field as a `CharField` with a [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='category.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title','description','body',''category')
```

To be able to update the `Article`'s category via the name, you have to make sure that `name` is a unique field for `Category`. If yes, then you can use a [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).

```
category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name')
```

Comment: Thanks, What about on updating the model?. How do I pass a string instead of  an Id

Comment: @frretyy You'll have to make sure that name is unique for a `Category`, otherwise it's not obvious which category and article refers to just by looking at its name.

Comment: Does it mean I need to change the name field on the Category model if i use SlugRelatedField?